# OpAmp Input Impedance vs Load resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, electronic-load, transimpedance-amplifier

I have below photodiode that provide low rise time based on 50 ohm load resistor. However I'm planning to use it with opamp in transimpedance configuration.

In this configuration, current is running through feedback resistance. So if I choose feedback resistor as 50 ohm, will they be same?

or should I consider input impedance of inverting input?

https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/d894487516cf2a67-2CB34855-B86A-20C9-EE57B7999E7F3C00/FDS015-SpecSheet.pdf

Comment: Your link doesn't work.  Do you have a particular opamp in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The input of a transimpedance amplifier is a virtual ground (very low impedance) in the region where the op amp has substantial loop gain.  (Independent of the feedback resistor for the most part.)  But the diode doesn't "need" a 50 ohm load, a lower impedance will give the same or faster risetime.

Comment: So photodiode does not see any load when it's connected to opamp in transimpedance configuration whatever the feedback resistor. Is this correct?

Comment: @LifeIsBeatiful The transimpedance input impedance is ideally zero, so the diode acts as if it were connected from (possibly) a bias voltage to ground.  Ideally, to a first order.  The loop gain response of the op-amp can tell you where the virtual ground is a good approximation.  The feedback resistor and parasitics will also have an effect.